# Passing a dictionary to as keyword parameters to a function

Tags: python

I have a function to compute sales:

```
def get_sales(
    sale_1: int,
    sale_2: int,
    sale_3: int,
    with_fees: bool = True,
) -> float:
    
    if with_fees is True:
        return (sale_1 + sale_2 + sale_3) * 0.95
    else:
        return (sale_1 + sale_2 + sale_3)
```

I also have a dictionary named `sales_test`:

```
sales_test = {'sale_1': 100,
              'sale_2': 75,
              'sale_3': 92,
              'revenue_1' : 400,
              'revenue_2' : 219,
              'city' : 'London'
              }
```

I'd like to be able to create another function named `advanced_sales` that takes in the `sales_test` dict and returns the `get_sales` output:

```
def advanced_sales(
    sales_test: Dict[str, int],
    with_fees: bool = True,
) -> float:

    sales = get_sales(**sales_test)
    return sales

advanced_sales(sales_test)
```

The desired output is:  `253.64999999999998`   (i.e. 100+75+92)

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
----> 6     sales = get_sales(**sales_test)
      7     return sales

TypeError: get_sales() got an unexpected keyword argument 'revenue_1'
```

Any assistance unpacking the `sales_test` dictionary would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You're unpacking it just fine.  But it contains more values than the function will accept.

Comment: A simple fix would be to add ``**kwargs`` at the end of your parameter list in the function to effectively ignore the extra dictionary elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass additional argument which the function cannot accept.
One way to address this would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sales_test = {'sale_1': 100,
              'sale_2': 75,
              'sale_3': 92,
              'revenue_1' : 400,
              'revenue_2' : 219,
              'city' : 'London'
              }
              
def get_sales(
    
    with_fees: bool = True,**kwargs,
) -> float:
    sale_1,sale_2,sale_3=kwargs['sale_1'],kwargs['sale_2'],kwargs['sale_3']
    if with_fees is True:
        return (sale_1 + sale_2 + sale_3) * 0.95
    else:
        return (sale_1 + sale_2 + sale_3)

def advanced_sales(
    sales_test=None,
    with_fees: bool = True,
) -> float:

    sales = get_sales(**sales_test,with_fees=with_fees)
    return sales

print(advanced_sales(sales_test))
```

Answer (score -2):

get_sales accepts only 4 argument but you are passing too many and no one of this is named revenue_1 etc.